# Connect SQLAlchemy with Google Cloud Spanner using Service Account

Tags: sqlalchemy, permissions, credentials, google-cloud-spanner

I try to retrieve data from Google Cloud Spanner data base. I create a service account, equipping it with the basic role "Owner" to ensure a maximum range of permissions. (I am owner of the project myself). I also add myself to as Service account users role and Service account admin role, just to max out my rights and permissions.

From this service account, I create service account JSON credentials. I provide access to this json file via an environment variable in my python code:

```
import os 
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="c17-bot-dd3cca1bd2f3.json"
```

and to be sure I enter in the terminal:

> export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="c17-bot-dd3cca1bd2f3.json"

That is my python code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
    
engine = create_engine(
            "spanner+spanner:///projects/c-17bot/instances/test-instance/databases/example-db"})
with engine.connect() as conn:
     result = conn.execute(text("SELECT SingerId, AlbumId, AlbumTitle FROM Albums"))
```

To really drive home the point that the json credentials are considered I also run the code:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("c17-bot-dd3cca1bd2f3.json")
engine = create_engine(
    "spanner+spanner:///projects/c-17bot/instances/test-instance/databases/example-db",
        connect_args={'client': spanner.Client(project="c-17bot", credentials = creds)}
)
```

In every case, I always receive the error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Caller is missing IAM
> permission spanner.sessions.create on resource
> projects/c-17bot/instances/test-instance/databases/example-db.

What roles do I have to assign to the service account and/or how do I successfully pass the credentials to the connection request such that the SQLAlchemy successfully retrieves the data?

Further information:

A CLI based successfully retrieves the data:

```
instance_id = "test-instance"
database_id = "example-db"
instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)
database = instance.database(database_id)
    with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
        results = snapshot.execute_sql(
            "SELECT SingerId, AlbumId, AlbumTitle FROM Albums"
        )
    
        for row in results:
            print("SingerId: {}, AlbumId: {}, AlbumTitle: {}".format(*row))
```

Answer (score 0):

The database user or reader role should suffice.